# Slicers showing all values - Power BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a table in Power BI Desktop which has multiple columns (5 Dimension data connected with a Fact table - Star Schema).

I have now added 3 Slicer to filter data in above table but when I select the first slicer then the other slicers should show only available dimensions data but it is showing all the available data.

I tried changing Cross filter Direction to **both** from **single** in Manage Relationship but it works for only one column but not to all with the below error or warning message.

[image]

**NOTE:** I do have few more Pages in the same Visualization report which contains separate fact table with same dimension keys.

Please let me know how to resolve this or any other suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following measure to filter through your dimensions

```
Cross Filter = INT( NOT( ISEMPTY( 'Your FACT TABLE') ) )
```

Then dragg this measure in every slicer into the filter pane and select the option **is equal to 1**.

My power bi version is in spanish but you will get the idea.

[image]

----------------------------------------

Comment: Thank you @Agustin, It works perfect as expected.